# How do I format the date with bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have a select drop down that activates two datepicker input field depending on what is selected. When one field is selected, I would like to fill in the value of today's date plus one year. However, when I select that, I get this: **Tue Aug 11 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)**. I would like to have the date as: mm/dd/yyyy.

I have setup a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/mwoods98/aku8ytju/
**Updated fiddle**

Here is a look at the code:

```
                 $(document).ready(function() {

                    $('#getHoldStatus').change(function()
                    {
                        var selected_item = $(this).val()
                        if(selected_item == "3"){
                            $('#datepicker').val("").removeClass('invisible');
                            $('#datepicker2').val("").removeClass('invisible');

                            var date = new Date("8/11/2014");
                            var date3 = new Date("8/11/2015");

                            $('#datepicker2').val(date3);
                            var newDate = new Date(date3.getFullYear(), date3.getMonth(), date3.getDate()+1);
                            $('#datepicker2').datepicker({ dateFormat: "mm/dd/yyyy" }); 


                        }
                        else if(selected_item == "2") {
                            $('#datepicker').val("").removeClass('invisible');
                            $('#datepicker2').val(selected_item).addClass('invisible');
                            $("#datepicker2").val('0');
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $('#datepicker').val(selected_item).addClass('invisible');
                            $('#datepicker2').val(selected_item).addClass('invisible');
                            $("#datepicker").val('');
                            $("#datepicker2").val('');

                        }
                    }
                    );

                        // put all your jQuery goodness in here.
                    });
```

I am manually setting the date here for now but I can't seem to get it formatted properly.

```
<label class="control-label" for="getHoldStatus"> 
                    Hold Status
                 </label>
                 <div class="controls">
                    <select id="getHoldStatus" name="getHoldStatus">
                          <option value=""></option>

                            <option value="1" >None</option>

                            <option value="3" >On Hold until Candidate Available</option>

                            <option value="2" >On Hold until Position Available</option>

                    </select>
                </div>



                 <label class="control-label" for="input08"> 
                    Hold Start Date
                 </label>
                 <div class="controls">
                    <script>
                        $(function() {
                        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({autoclose: true, todayHighlight: true, orientation: "bottom right"});
                          });
                    </script>

                        <div><input type="text" id="datepicker" value="" name="fdfHoldStartDate" class="invisible" /></div>

                </div>



                 <label class="control-label" for="input09"> 
                    Hold End Date
                 </label>
                 <div class="controls">
                    <script>
                        $(function() {
                        $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({format: "mm/dd/yyyy", autoclose: true, todayHighlight: true});
                          });
                    </script>

                        <div><input type="text" id="datepicker2" value="" name="fdfHoldEndDate" class="invisible" /></div>

                </div>
```

UPDATE: For some reason, the fiddle did not update. I have confirmed it and now the source appears relevant to the question I was asking. You can see how the date is being formatted when a selection is made.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this: [Bootstrap 3 datepicker - code generator](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&todayBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox)

```
<input type="text" type="text" id="date1">
$('#date1').datepicker({
     format: "mm-dd-yyyy"
});
```

Comment: Sorry it's bootstrap 2. I forgot to mention that.

Comment: work too, it's the same code.
but you can check the page, there is a button switch to bootstrap 2, or 3.

Comment: You can take a look at the doc: [Doc Datepicker](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/)

Comment: well, i updated your fiddle, should work now for the datepicker2
[fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/aku8ytju/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `format` instead of `formatDate`:

```
$('#datepicker2').datepicker({ format: "mm/dd/yyyy" });
```

The check in/check out example should be useful: [**Datepicker for Bootstrap**](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/)